# High server load after upgrading to MySql5.5

Tags: mysql

Around 10 hours ago we upgraded our server from 5.0. to 5.5 and currently the load on server is 150

When I do show process list I see a lot of queries with status

```
Waiting for query cache lock
```

And I get following output for SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Qcache%';

```
+-------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name           | Value    |
+-------------------------+----------+
| Qcache_free_blocks      | 1        |
| Qcache_free_memory      | 33536864 |
| Qcache_hits             | 0        |
| Qcache_inserts          | 0        |
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes    | 0        |
| Qcache_not_cached       | 1463936  |
| Qcache_queries_in_cache | 0        |
| Qcache_total_blocks     | 1        |
+-------------------------+----------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Query cache param is set to

```
query_cache_size=32M
```

Our server is a single node with 8GB ram not sure why query cache is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on serverfault it self, high load was because query cache was not working and query cache was not working because there was a hyphen in the database name.

When I renamed the database without hypen all went back to normal.

Reference to the ticket
[MySQL 5.5.9 Query Cache not working when schemas have hyphens ("-") in their name](https://serverfault.com/questions/246735/mysql-5-5-9-query-cache-not-working-when-schemas-have-hyphens-in-their-nam?rq=1)

Thanks
Hussain